# Is it possible to view a shape throught a specific shader in camera view? Real time, eevee, no comp (kind of shader holdout)

Tags: rigging, 3d-view, shaders, eevee-render-engine

The pupil is in front of the head. Is it possible to make it visible only in the white part of the eye according to the camera view? Like a kind of shader holdout inverted and limited to mask the pupil. In real time with eevee (I know the solution with compositing).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try with a boolean, a shapekey, or even simpler, only use 2 poses: eyes open, eyes closed

Comment: I thought about this kind of solution but I think the shader solution is more optimized, if possible. boolean are very resource-intensive. And for a good 2d style eye closing, I need at least 3 poses.

Comment: what do you mean with "according to the camera view"?

Comment: It is a bit like a 2d boolean depending on a projection view: the result must be that the pupil appears in the area delimited by the white shader and it is cut outside. As the pupil's cutout is different according to the point of view, I specify that it must be according to the point of view of the camera. (not like a 3d boolean who doesn't change according to the view).